# How to Avoid React State Getting Applied to All Items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to add a strikethrough to li item when a tick mark button is clicked ,i am able to do that by storing the val in some state but the problem is if i add a new list item the strike through is getting auto applied on the new li also kindly suggest a way how to fix it
kindly check at

```js
 const [line, setline] = useState(false);
  const [ll, setll] = useState(false);
  const markdone = () => {
    setline(true);
  
    // setll(true);
  };
```

using line to manage states on li style

```js
  const [input, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  // passing  entered
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const lp = (event) => {
    // let c = [1,2,34,55]

    event.preventDefault();
    // if no input nothing will happen return none
    if (!input) return;
    // using spread operator its used whenever we need to add array data to exiting array
    const newTodos = [...todos, input];

    setTodos(newTodos);
    // clearing input text
    setValue("");
  
  };
  const handeldel = (index) => {
    // console.log(index)

    todos.splice(index, 1);
    setTodos([...todos]);

    // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
    // setTodos([...newTodos]);
  };
  const [line, setline] = useState(false);
  const [ll, setll] = useState(false);
  const markdone = () => {
    setline(true);
  
    // setll(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center font-weight-bolder alert-info mb-5">
        Tasks To Do <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list text-success"></i>
      </h1>
      <div class="input-group mb-3 container">
        <input
          className="form-control border-primary font-weight-bold"
          style={{ height: 60 }}
          placeholder="Enter Text here"
          type="text"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleInput}
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button
            className="input-group-append font-weight-bolder "
            style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
            onClick={lp}
          >
            {" "}
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-2x p-2"></i>{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {todos.map((x, index) => (
        <ol style={{ listStyle: "outside" }} className="container">
          <li
            className="font-weight-bolder table-bordered text-capitalize alert-secondary "
            style={{
              fontSize: 30,
              textDecoration: line ? "line-through" : "none",
              backgroundColor: ll ? "Chartreuse" : "none",
             
            }}
          >
            {x}
            <i
              class="fas fa-check-circle float-md-right text-success"
              onClick={markdone}
            ></i>{" "}
            <i
              class="fas fa-trash-alt  text-danger float-md-right"
              onClick={() => handeldel(index)}
            ></i>
          </li>
        </ol>
      ))}
```

Comment: What is `line`? `ll`? `lp`? `markdone`? `handeldel`? It's hard to help when we only have a fragment of the code.

Comment: Either way, you will need to rethink your data model – each todo item needs to have its own `done` flag, doesn't it?

Comment: i'm gonna take a wild guess here that you're storing 1 value/field/flag in state for the strikethroughs. you need to store a value for each list item, whether you use an array or object, the point is, each list item needs to know about it's own striked state

Comment: have modified the question can u plz check now

Answer (score 1):

One solution to keep your code simple is to create a new Component named for example `TodoItem`and let him be responsible of it's proper state. something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function TodoItem(props) {
  const [line, setline] = useState(false);
  const [ll, setll] = useState(false);
  const markdone = () => {
    setline((prevState) => !prevState);

    setll((prevState) => !prevState);
  };
  return (
    <li
      className="font-weight-bolder table-bordered text-capitalize alert-secondary "
      style={{
        fontSize: 30,
        textDecoration: line ? "line-through" : "none",
        backgroundColor: ll ? "Chartreuse" : "transparent"
      }}
    >
      {props.todo}
      <button onClick={markdone}>{!ll ? "done" : "undone"}</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={props.handeldel}>delete</button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

this component get the todo value by props from the parents and trig the delete function pass in props to.
As you can see I change the none to transparent for the backgroundColor too.
And then in the parent you can add it in the map:

```
 <ol style={{ listStyle: "outside" }} className="container">
        {todos.map((x, index) => (
          <TodoItem
            key={x.id}
            todo={x.text}
            handeldel={() => handeldel(x.id)}
          />
```

As you can see I create a "todo" object `{id:string, text:string }` instead of a simple string because you need to pass a key when you are mapping in JSX and passing the index will cause you an issue like in this gif:
[image]
to avoid this issue I choose to use a little package call [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) to generate uuid for me (but you can do whatever you want as long as evry id are unique).
So to "create" a todo object you just do something like:

```
  const lp = (event) => {
    // let c = [1,2,34,55]

    event.preventDefault();
    // if no input nothing will happen return none
    if (!input) return;
    // using spread operator its used whenever we need to add array data to exiting array
    const newTodos = [...todos, { id: shortid.generate(), text: input }];

    setTodos(newTodos);
    // clearing input text
    setValue("");
  };
```

And this change a bit your delete function that could look like:

```
const handeldel = (id) => {
    // console.log(index)

    const newList = todos.filter((t) => t.id !== id);
    console.log(newList);
    setTodos(newList);

    // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
    // setTodos([...newTodos]);
  };
```

an overview of all the parent (or page component):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import shortid from "shortid";
export default function Todo() {
  const [input, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  // passing  entered
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const lp = (event) => {
    // let c = [1,2,34,55]

    event.preventDefault();
    // if no input nothing will happen return none
    if (!input) return;
    // using spread operator its used whenever we need to add array data to exiting array
    const newTodos = [...todos, { id: shortid.generate(), text: input }];

    setTodos(newTodos);
    // clearing input text
    setValue("");
  };
  const handeldel = (id) => {
    // console.log(index)

    const newList = todos.filter((t) => t.id !== id);
    console.log(newList);
    setTodos(newList);

    // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
    // setTodos([...newTodos]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center font-weight-bolder alert-info mb-5">
        Tasks To Do <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list text-success"></i>
      </h1>
      <div className="input-group mb-3 container">
        <input
          className="form-control border-primary font-weight-bold"
          style={{ height: 60 }}
          placeholder="Enter Text here"
          type="text"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleInput}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button
            className="input-group-append font-weight-bolder "
            style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
            onClick={lp}
          >
            OK
            <i className="fas fa-plus-square fa-2x p-2"></i>{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ol style={{ listStyle: "outside" }} className="container">
        {todos.map((x, index) => (
          <TodoItem
            key={x.id}
            todo={x.text}
            handeldel={() => handeldel(x.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wonderful-bird-or0b1]

Answer (score 0):

As people on the comments suggest, each todo item needs to have its own status to display correctly. I use an array to keep track of tasks that were completed.

```
const [completedTasks, setCompletedTasks] = useState([]);
```

When an item is marked done, put that item in the completed tasks array. I use the value to distinguish between todo items because using indexes may cause unexpected outcomes.

```
  const markdone = (e, x) => {
      setCompletedTask(prevState => [...prevState, x]);
  };
```

To apply style for done tasks, check if todo item is on the completed tasks like below

```
 {todos.map((x, index) => (
        <ol style={{ listStyle: "outside" }} className="container">
          <li
            className="font-weight-bolder table-bordered text-capitalize alert-secondary "
            style={{
              fontSize: 30,
              textDecoration: completedTask.find(item => item === x) ? "line-through" : "none",
              backgroundColor: completedTask.find(item => item === x) ? "Chartreuse" : "none",
             
            }}
          >
            {x}
            <i
              class="fas fa-check-circle float-md-right text-success"
              onClick={(e) => markdone(e, x)}
            ></i>{" "}
            <i
              class="fas fa-trash-alt  text-danger float-md-right"
              onClick={() => handeldel(index)}
            ></i>
          </li>
        </ol>
      ))}
```

Don't forget to remove it from completed tasks (if it's completed) when you delete the item

```
 const handeldel = (index) => {
    // Remove the task on completed tasks when you click remove
    setCompletedTasks(prevState => {
         const arr = [...prevState];
         const taskInx = arr.indexOf(todos[index]);
         if (taskInx !== -1) {
            arr.splice(taskInx, 1);
         }
         return arr;
    })
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    setTodos([...todos]);

    // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
    // setTodos([...newTodos]);
  };
```